# $http.post data format in AngularJs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angular-http

Problem Question:

I am making a post call to my API but keep on getting 500 server error. After doing some debugging API is expecting data in different format

API excepting --

```
user[email] -- json would be {user =>{email=>'test@test.com'}
```

I am sending as

```
return $http.post(urlBase + '/users/password',{email: email});
json is like {"user":"test@test.com"}
```

Recently started learning. So please guide me or provide me with any resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send this:

```
{"user": {"email":"test@test"}}
```

This is similar to:

```
user.email = "test@test";
```

In your case:

```
return $http.post(urlBase + '/users/password',{user:{email: email}});
```

This is a good reference for this: [JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlBase + '/users/password',
    data: $.param({email: email})               
});
```

OR

```
 $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: urlBase + '/users/password',
    params: {email: email}                         
);
```